# About the cin function to an object of all public members

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ primer 5th edition and I have confronted with an problem.

In the section 7.1 of the book, it has some code kind of like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string;

struct Sales_data{
    string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

int main()
{
    Sales_data total;
    cin >> total;
}
```

I know that if members of `Sales_data` are all private members, then `cin>>total` must be wrong because cin is not  friend functions of `Sales_data`.

I also know that `cin >> total.bookNo>> total.units_sold >> total.revenue` are absolutely right.

But now members of `Sales_data` are all public. Can I use `cin` to read `total` as a whole? I have seen many codes like `cin >> total` in C++ primer.

Comment: You should either stick to `cin >> total.bookNo>> total.units_sold >> total.revenue` since they're public , or create a method to input them in one call.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Why dose the book write codes like `cin>>total` ?

Comment: They might have written an overridden function somewhere , or assumptions. See @Ulrich's answer below for operator overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, operators like `>>` are functions with a special calling syntax. You can overload functions like `operator>>` for your type:

```
istream&
operator>>(istream& in, Sales_data& v)
{
    in >> v.bookNo >> v.units_sold >> v.revenue;
    return in;
}
```

If you want to make the members private, you need to make the overloaded operator a friend of your class:

```
struct Sales_data
{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Sales_data& v);
private:
    string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold;
    double revenue;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though until now I can't understand your code coz I just finished chapter 7 about classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine the operator >> if you want to change the whole structure.

try to read this [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/17792/)